# multi dimensional php associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP code

```
      $RTPerDate['revenue'][$DateGroupped['date']] += $telco['revenue'];
      $RTPerDate['traffics'][$DateGroupped['date']] += $telco['traffics'];
```

Which produce this array

```
Array(
[revenue] => Array
    (
        [2015-10-01] => 166600
        [2015-10-02] => 578300
    )
[traffics] => Array
    (
        [2015-10-01] => 167
        [2015-10-02] => 576
    )
```

I want to make the array looks like this

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [revenue] => 166600
        [traffics] => 167
        [date] => 2015-10-01
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [revenue] => 578300
        [traffics] => 576
        [date] => 2015-10-02
    )
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Do you perhaps mean you want it indexed by date?

```
$RTPerDate[$DateGroupped['date']]['revenue'] += $telco['revenue'];
$RTPerDate[$DateGroupped['date']]['traffics'] += $telco['traffics'];

Array(
[2015-10-01] => Array
    (
        [revenue] => 166600
        [traffics] => 578300
    )
[2015-10-02] => Array
    (
        [revenue] => 167
        [traffics] => 576
    )
```

**Initial Answer**

Something like this?

```
$RTPerDate[0]['revenue'] += $telco['revenue'];
$RTPerDate[0]['traffics'] += $telco['traffics'];
$RTPerDate[0]['date'] = $DateGroupped['date'];

$RTPerDate[1]['revenue'] += $telco['revenue'];
$RTPerDate[1]['traffics'] += $telco['traffics'];
$RTPerDate[1]['date'] = $DateGroupped['date'];
```

Comment: Thanks but not that one. Your solution will break the date group. The script is sum the revenue on each date so it is assumed that there are some revenue on the same date

Comment: I have made the array look the way you asked. Can you give more information on how it works and the intended functionality of the program? Put it in the description and show examples if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$field['revenue'][$DateGroupped['date']] += $telco['revenue'];
$field['traffics'][$DateGroupped['date']] += $telco['traffics'];

$RTPerDate[]['revenue'] = $field['revenue'][$DateGroupped['date']];
$RTPerDate[]['traffics'] = $field['traffics'][$DateGroupped['date']];
$RTPerDate[]['date'] = $DateGroupped['date'];
```

**var_dump($RTPerDate)** to view formatted arrays.

Comment: it returns the same result as the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I did small modification so the code like this

```
$RTPerDate[$DateGroupped['date']]['revenue'] += $telco['TheRevenue'];
$RTPerDate[$DateGroupped['date']]['traffics'] += $telco['TheTraffics'];
$RTPerDate[$DateGroupped['date']]['date'] = $DateGroupped['date'];
```

And so the array becomes like this

```
Array (
[2015-10-02] => Array
    (
        [revenue] => 578300
        [traffics] => 576
        [date] => 2015-10-02
    )

[2015-10-03] => Array
    (
        [revenue] => 12825
        [traffics] => 13
        [date] => 2015-10-03
    )
)
```

Comment: "[date] => 2015-10-03" is redundant, its already stored as the index to itself. Excluding that, the result is exactly my answer. Please mark a correct answer.